# Flutter Web url name incorrect

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

Flutter Web url name is converted to number instead of displaying the correct name.

Example: 
correct name: '/tests/screen' 
displayed: '6'

[image]

How to correct that?

Comment: add your router code

Comment: @SajadRezvani I use Flutter Modular (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular) for routing